# Convert Custom List to Document Library SP2013

Tags: document-library, custom-list

I have a Custom List that I want to convert to a Document library. All the fields are identical. Is there any easy way of doing this? I'm using SP2013.

Answer (score 2):

There is no inbuilt mechanism say OOTB facility to do such task. But still you can do this with little bit of lazy steps.

Or also you can go with C# custom solution.

For detail information of converting custom list to Document Library you can go with this [SharePoint - Convert a list to a library](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10333274/convert-a-list-to-a-library.aspx) once.

Also if you have document attached in your current list and you want to migrate it into the Document Library then you can go with this [Move/Migrate SharePoint List Attachments to Document Library with Created and Modified Date](http://dishasharepointworld.blogspot.in/2012/03/movemigrate-sharepoint-list-attachments.html)

Let me know whether this approach helpful to you or not.

Comment: The problem is that there are many fields within the custom list, of varying formats, choices lists, etc etc.

Comment: The problem is that there are many fields within the custom list, of varying formats, choices lists, lookups from other tables, etc etc. You name it, it has it.

Normally I would just recreate it from scratch, but the complexity of the custom list is very daunting. The C# option is looking interesting, just working out if I can do this via javascript. Not sure if it will pick up all the external list cross references though.

Comment: That's why in past i gone through the c# code, it was easy for me to migrate the fields from list to library. I know this is not the ultimate solution, its just an approach. I too working at my end. Will let you know once i come up with best approach.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going with easy approach you should choose best practice. This will help in the long run.

Best practice is to create Content Types and add it to the document library. So first create a Document Content Type and add the required fields (site columns).